# C# Winforms DataGridView.Row setting custom color

Tags: c#, datagridview, background-color

I am setting different colors to different rows in a DataGridView, depending on their contents:

```
row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor  = _myColor;
```

Everything works fine if _myColor is something like Color.Green or Color(255, 180, 95), but it does not accept colors with deviating alpha values, like Color(128, Color.Green).[image: DataGridView rows with and without alpha value]

In the figure above the first row is an attempt to assign a color with alpha != 255 (always gray and not completely drawn), the second row is with an assigned known color.

Is it a feature or a bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug in DataGridView; I have tried it in different ways; whenever the alpha value is different from 255, the row is not drawn properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Color.FromArgb()` or `Color.FromName()` methods

Comment: Thanks for the tip.Yes, I did and in my opinion it does not work either.